# PHPUnit Test Exception and AssertEquals

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm actually trying to understand PHPUNIT and unit testing with PHP.

I have a classic divide methode.

```
 public function divide($firstNumber, $secondNumber){
    if( !is_numeric($firstNumber) ||  !is_numeric($secondNumber) ){
        throw new Exception("Not a number") ; 
    }
    if(  $secondNumber == 0 ) throw new Exception("Can't divide by zero") ; 

    return $firstNumber/$secondNumber ; 
}
```

As you can see It can return a Number or Exception.
Here is the testDivide code that I used.

```
 /**
 * @dataProvider diviserDateProvider
 * @covers MyTools::diviser     
 */
public function testDivide($firstNumber, $secondNumber, $expected) {
    $myToolsClasse = new MyTools();
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $myToolsClasse->diviser($firstNumber, $secondNumber));



}

public function diviserDateProvider() {
    return array(
        array(1, 0, new Exception("Can't divide by zero")),
        array(1, 2, 0.5),
        array("", "", 0.5)
    );
}
```

As you can see there is a DataProvider with multiple testing values.
The problem is I have to Except/Assert an Exception which is the best way to do it ?

Should I use @exceptException and use try catch in my testDivide code ? 
Thanks for your help
have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$this->expectException(\Exception::class);
$this->expectExceptionMessage('Expected Exception Message');
```

https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions.examples.ExceptionTest.php

Answer (score 3):

The [best practice](https://thephp.cc/news/2016/02/questioning-phpunit-best-practices) for testing exceptions with PHPUnit is to use `expectException()` in your test method's code.

Comment: Exactly I used @ExpectException annotation but i need a testMethod where I can use AssertEquals for 2 values that wont throw a exception. And 1 assert that will throw an exception... So, is it possible to assertequals and "assert" in a same test method ? or I should sperate them...

Comment: I proposed using the `expectException()` method, not the `@expectedException` annotation.

Comment: @Joe you can put them together in the same test, but of course you will need to take care (and remember) that their order matters (the exception should be thrown *after* the asserts, because it prevents the method from continuing its execution). It strongly depends on what is the aspect you are testing, but (for how PHPUnit works at the moment) is not advisable and I would suggest to test asserts and exceptions in two different methods.